# Update a specific power query table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, refresh

I'm getting an error on the following code. I'm trying to update a specific power query query that is displayed in a Table in a specific worksheet. I'd like to have a timer run while this is happening and display the results in another worksheet.

```vb
   Sub Refresh_All_Data_Connections()
        Dim timerWs As Worksheet
        Dim startTime As Double
        Dim endTime As Double
        Dim elapsedTime As Double
        Dim timerCell As Range
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim objConnection As WorkbookConnection
        Dim bBackground As Boolean
            
            ' Store the start time
            startTime = Timer
            
             ' Store the end time
            endTime = Timer
            
            Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2023 YTD_Models")
            
            For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
                'Get current background-refresh value
                bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        
                'Temporarily disable background-refresh
                objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        
                'Refresh this connection
                objConnection.Refresh
        
                'Set background-refresh value back to original value
                objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
            Next
    sh.ListObjects("YTD_Models").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
   ' Calculate the elapsed time in seconds
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime
    
    ' Specify the worksheet and target cell where the time will be displayed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set timerWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If timerWs Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Timer sheet not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set timerCell = timerWs.Range("H14")
    
    ' Display the elapsed time in the specified cell
    timerCell.Value = "Refresh Time: " & Format(elapsedTime, "0.00") & " seconds"
    
    
    End Sub
```

I keep getting a Run-Time error '1004', application-defined or object-defined error on this part of the code:
bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

Comment: he error may not necessarily be related to the VBA code itself. To troubleshoot, please attempt a manual refresh of all data connections to ensure they are functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can confirm that the individual connections work fine if i refresh them manually

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem you're experiencing because I don't have the same table connection in my worksheet. However, In your code, it's better to explicitly declare the data types for each variable to ensure clarity and avoid any potential issues.

```
'Dim objConnection, bBackground
Dim objConnection As WorkbookConnection
Dim bBackground As Boolean
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. I updated the code and ran it, it took a few minutes before it gave me a run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error. The error was on the following part of the code:   
bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

Comment: I would put Debug.Print objConnection before the error line, and see which sheet caused this issue. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for that. When I ran the Debug.Print... it looks like to run through Each objConnection in the workbook as it lists every one (I have about 30 power query pulls in this workbook). Is there a way to update the code so that it only looks for a specific pull? Some of the pulls I don't want to be refreshed, like all the prior year data.

Comment: Yes, Debug.print will print all names in workbook until it get stop. So, the last printed name this the problem sheet.